# In ggplot2/stat_summary, how to add the `median` value as label to plot (as geom_text())

Tags: ggplot2

In ggplot2/stat_summary, how to add the `median` value as label to plot ? Thanks!

```
library(ggplot2)
d <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + geom_point()
d + stat_summary(fun = "median", colour = "red", size = 2, geom = "point")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One potential option is to use [`after_stat()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_eval.html) to get the labels, i.e.

```r
library(ggplot2)
d <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) +
  geom_point()

d + stat_summary(fun = "median", colour = "red", size = 4,
                 geom = "text", aes(label = after_stat(y)),
                 position = position_nudge(x = 0.25))
```

[image]

---

To round the values, you can use `round()`:

```r
d + stat_summary(fun = "median", colour = "red", size = 4,
                 geom = "text", aes(label = round(after_stat(y), 0)),
                 position = position_nudge(x = 0.25))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: it's greate , Thanks for your replay!

Comment: If my numbers have more decimal places than required, how would I pass stat_summary the instructions to limit to say 1 decimal place?

Comment: You can use `round()` - I'll edit my answer @MarkNeal

Comment: Thanks, That is much neater than the option I had, which used a custom function as argument to ‘fun =‘